# 404 error springboot restcontroller requestmapping

Tags: spring, rest, request-mapping

I have a simple web application with springboot (netbeans 8.2), but resource mapping does not work, I have 2 days with the problem. any ideas?

ApplicationContext://///////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/springXML8"/>
```

WEB.XML ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

        <display-name>example</display-name>

        <absolute-ordering />




        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>ServletCentral</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>


        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>ServletCentral</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

ServletConfig:////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!--  paquete a escanear en busca de componentes -->

         <mvc:annotation-driven/>


</beans>
```

Application://////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
```

}

Controller:///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
@RestController
public class controller1 {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello(){
       return "Lain love this service"; 
    }


}
```

POM://///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>beans</groupId>
    <artifactId>beans</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <name>SpringXML8</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. 
In itself what is your problem? How u are testing? Are you using postman, soap ui?

Based on your mapping your "url-pattern"/* "url-pattern" in web.xml is empty, so you don´t need anymore in your URL Request. But you have little issues. Why do you have two Spring appCtx (ApplicationContext & ServletConfig)??

You do not provide more information. I don't know if you are trying to raise a Tomcat server or simple spring boot server default. You could stay just with ServletConfig, you shouldn't have -Context path="/springXML8"-

You could replace this with a @ResquestMapping global in your RestController. i.e.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("initialLoginOrSpringXML8")
public class PersonalController {
@RequestMapping("/getHello")
public String hello(){
return "Lain love this service";
}
}
```

Besides I suggest to add some word in your local @RequestMapping by method.

Remember if you use @RequestParams or @PathVariable, you must enter them especially depending on the test client you are using. As well as the type of request Http

Comment: I know I can modify
path = "/ spring XML 8", but if I do nothing happens.

My problem is that I cannot see the return of my hello method in the browser. When executing the program I get a 404 error instead of the method exit. I don't know if it's my netbeans or it's code. I don't know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

@Diego Caballero

There are many options for which you have this error. The most common is a bad mapping of the URL.

1. The server may be confused by the 2 settings, it may not know which context path to respect. Verify the URL you are using, try different options, combinations.
2. Change

```html
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

to

<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Currently, your mapped DispatcherServlet is marked as handling all requests because of /*. This means that it will also attempt to handle a request dispatched to /WEB-INF/*** It obviously doesn't have a handler for that and will fail.

The pattern / is special in that it is the default fallback if no other pattern matches. If there's a Servlet that maps to the request path, that Servlet will be chosen before your mapped DispatcherServlet. (This maybe is your case).

3. Try to log everything you can. Use level of info, error and debug, of log4j. Also try to read the server logs (this is located in the folder where you downloaded it). Not only the console of your actual IDE.
4. Verify if you are deploying correctly the application. Maven cycle, etc. WAR or JAR?
5. Are you using the correct domain? localhost? or maybe is an ip or a diffente domain setted in the server options deploy

I hope it was a little help. Regards